# What camera used the largest EXR sensor, and which one offered the largest EXR pixels?

Tags: sensor, fujifilm, sensor-size

I learned to appreciate Fuji's EXR sensor technology for travel and reporting photography when I used a Fuji X10. But like with all compact cameras, I feel a larger sensor and / or pixel size would have been nice.

Given that the EXR technology seems to have reached its end of life, I feel that the following questions can be authoritatively answered:

Which camera offered the largest EXR sensor in the history of the technology's development, and how big was it?

And, most likely relevant for low light work, which camera offered the largest pixel size of the EXR sensors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first generation of EXR sensors were SuperCCD EXR and produced in 1/2.3" and 1/1.6" sizes. When Fuji switched to CMOS, they introduced the EXR CMOS in 2/3" and 1/2.3" sizes. The largest being the 2/3" sensor which is present in the X10.

EXR cameras all had *EXR* initially in their name, so they are easy to identify:

- F200 EXR
- S200 EXR
- F70 EXR
- F80 EXR
- Z800 EXR
- F300 EXR. This is also the first camera with on-sensor Phase-Detect AF.

Then, EXR CMOS cameras also used the same naming, except when starting with the letter *X*:

- HS20 EXR
- F550 EXR
- F500 EXR
- Z900 EXR
- F600 EXR
- X10 (2/3")
- F605 EXR
- F505 EXR
- Z1000 EXR
- HS30 EXR
- HS25 EXR
- F770 EXR
- F750 EXR
- F660 EXR
- F800 EXR
- F850 EXR
- X-S1
- XF1 (2/3")
- HS50 EXR
- F900 EXR. Introduced Phase-Detect on an EXR CMOS sensor.
- F1000 EXR

The larger sensors and pixel sizes were effectively used in the X10 and XF1 which shared the same 12 megapixels 2/3" EXR-CMOS sensor.

Comment: Great comprehensive answer, thanks! So there never was a larger EXR sensor than in the X10... Pity. I was hoping to discover a little-known APS-C EXR camera :-)

Comment: Most EXR sensors were actually 1/2" slightly larger that 1/2.3" .
X-s1 also used the 12mp 2/3" sensor